# Parsing arrays on JADE Template Engine

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, pug

I'm using JADE template engine with ExpressJS.

sending this array to JADE template

```
var data = {
    "labels" : ["Label 1", "Label 2"]
};
res.render('index', {data: data});
```

And my JADE file looks like this:

```
script(type='text/javascript').
  var options = {
  labels: [#{data.labels}],
  ...
  };
```

As you see I'm trying to get `data.labels` values to inline `<script>` block of my JADE file. But output is like this:

```
<script type="...">
var options = {
      labels: [Label 1, Label 2], <-- invalid syntax
      ...
      };
```

it must be like this:

```
<script type="...">
var options = {
      labels: ["Label 1", "Label 2"], <-- valid syntax
      ...
      };
```

What should I do to use an array directly in JADE file?

Comment: What happen if you try labels: !{data.labels} ?

Comment: @JoseHermosillaRodrigo same as `#{...}`. BTW I've forgot a comma in that `invalid syntax` line. Updated question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSON makes things right:

```js
// magic of JSON.stringify:
var src = "script var labels = !{JSON.stringify(labels)}";

// let's try and render it:
var data = {
    "labels" : ["Label 1", "Label 2"]
};
var fn = jade.compile(src);

var html = fn(data);

console.log(html);
// output: <script>var labels = ["Label 1","Label 2"]</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jade/1.11.0/jade.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hello Amadan, thank you for your answer. But I couldn't apply this method to my project. Yes it's working on client-side (with jade.min.js file). But NodeJS won't recognize `jade.compile()` function?

Comment: The magic is in the first line: `!{JSON.stringify(...)}`. The rest is just so I can render Jade in Stack Overflow.

Comment: it's my bad, you are right. It's working now, thank you!